# If y elseif en powershell

Tags: condiciones, variables, powershell

Buenas tardes a todos :)
Se practicamente nada de powershell
Estoy probando el siguiente codigo (Es una prueba)

```
$java = Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_321/README.txt" -PathType Leaf 

if ($java -eq False)

{

  Write-Output "No Instalanda"

}

elseif ($java -eq True)

{

  Write-Output "Instalada"

}

pause
```

creo una variable con un comando y con if y elseif miro si es igual a True o False y segun la salida muestro un mensaje. No hay manera de hacerlo funcionar. Si pongo entre comillas los True o False siempre me da error.

Que tiene mal el ejemplo que puse?
Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un ejemplo puede ilustrar la diferencia entre if y elseif.

if es una nueva prueba, independiente del resultado de la prueba anterior.  elseif no tiene efecto si la prueba anterior dió éxito.

En el ejemplo, suponiendo que java no esta instalada,  los primeros dos ensayos solo resultan en una linea de salida, mientras que el último ensayo resulta en dos lineas.

```
$java = Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_321/README.txt" -PathType Leaf 

if ($java -eq $false)
{
  Write-Output "No Instalada"
}
else 
{
  Write-Output "Instalada"
}
"   "

if ($java -eq $false)
{
  Write-Output "No Instalada"
}
elseif ($true) 
{
  Write-Output "Instalada"
}
"   "
if ($java -eq $false)
{
  Write-Output "No Instalada"
}
if ($true)
{
  Write-Output "Siempre ejecutada"
}
pause
```